# Sort array in ascending order

Tags: javascript, arrays

Array: `var ranges = ["3-5", "1-4", "0-9", "10-10"];`

I tried the following function:

```
ranges.sort();

// Output: 0-9,1-4,10-10,3-5

// Desired output: 0-9,1-4,3-5,10-10
```

Any idea how I can get to desired output?

Comment: The `.sort()` method can be passed a comparator function.

Comment: `String` comparison is different than `number` comparison...

Comment: Have a read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsort

Comment: What should the sort do, use the first number as a numeric to determine, or apply the math subtraction and sort?

Comment: `Number 2 < 10` but `String 10 < 2`

Comment: @Will No need for result of subtraction they're just ranges and not equations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to sort by the first number, the approach is:

```
var desire = ranges.sort(function(a,b){return parseInt(a)-parseInt(b)});
```

Explanation: `parseInt(a)` just removes everything after the non-number, i.e. `-` and returns the number.

If you also want to make it sort by the first number properly if you have ranges starting with the same numbers (i.e. `3-5` and `3-7`):

```
var desire = ranges.sort(function(a,b){
   return (c=parseInt(a)-parseInt(b))?c:a.split('-')[1]-b.split('-')[1]
});
```

Explanation: works as the first one until the first numbers are equal; then it checks for the second numbers (thanks [Michael Geary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202830/michael-geary) for idea!)

If you want to sort by the result of equation, go for

```
var desire = ranges.sort(function(a,b){return eval(a)-eval(b)});
```

Explanation: `eval(a)` just evaluates the expression and passes the result.

Also, as [mentioned by h2ooooooo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442270/sort-array-in-ascending-order/34442373#comment56626396_34442373), you can specify the radix to avoid unpredictable behavior (i.e. `parseInt(a, 10)`).

Comment: [*Always specify the radix of the number by using `parseInt(n, 10)` rather than `parseInt(n)`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt): "***Always specify this parameter** to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior ... **usually** defaulting the value to 10*"

Comment: Thanks @nicael no need for result of subtraction but thank you anyway. They're just ranges and not equations.

Comment: @h2o have you ever experienced the unpredictable behavior?

Comment: @nicael: The page h2ooooooo linked to explains it. In particular, "If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal) or 10 (decimal).  Exactly which radix is chosen is implementation-dependent.  ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used, but not all browsers support this yet." So in older browsers, you may find that `parseInt('031')` returns decimal 25.

Comment: @nicael: Also, watch out for those `.replace('-','')` calls in your second example. In what order will the ranges `[ '11-12', '1-200' ]` be sorted?

Comment: @Michael Tried to deal with it by weighing the pairs by the length of the first number.

Comment: @nicael: That is an interesting approach. Here's a new test case for you: `[ '20-200', '4-400', '10-11' ]`

Comment: @Michael already realized it doesn't work somewhere, finding workarounds.

Comment: @Michael stopped smartassing and used your idea :D

Comment: I hope my ongoing code review is helpful and not annoying. :-) The algorithm looks sound in the latest version. The code inadvertently creates a global variable `c`. As h2ooooooo noted above, experienced JS developers may still be troubled by the use of `parseInt()` without a radix, even if the octal gotcha is gone in modern browsers. Finally, the code uses two different techniques (`parseInt` vs. `split`) to extract the range beginning and range end. Since these values are similar *kinds* of things, perhaps the same technique could be used for both instead of two different methods?

Comment: @Michael As for the global variable, I'm aware of that, but hey, it's golfing ;) Why did I use `parseInt(a)` in the second example instead of `a.split('-')[0]`? It's shorter :) I'll check and consider the radix.

Answer (score 2):

One thing your test case doesn't exercise is ranges that begin with the same value but have different ending values, for example:

```
[ "3-5", "1-5", "1-4", "10-9", "0-9", "10-10" ];
```

Presumably you would want those sorted in this order:

```
[ "0-9", "1-4", "1-5", "3-5", "10-9", "10-10" ]
```

Here's a sort function that sorts by the beginning of each range, and secondarily by the end of each range. So if two ranges start with the same value, the range that ends earlier will sort first.

```
function sortRanges( range ) {
    return ranges.sort( function( a, b ) {
        var aSplit = a.split( '-' ), aStart = aSplit[0], aEnd = aSplit[1];
        var bSplit = b.split( '-' ), bStart = bSplit[0], bEnd = bSplit[1];
        return aStart - bStart ? aStart - bStart : aEnd - bEnd;
    });
}

var ranges = [ "3-5", "1-5", "1-4", "10-9", "0-9", "10-10" ];
console.log( sortRanges( ranges ) );
```

This logs the result above.

How it works: The `sort()` function calls a comparator function with two arguments which are two array elements to be compared. This function must return a negative, positive, or zero value to indicate the sort order for these two elements.

So we split each range to get its start and end values, and then simply subtract the start values. If the result is nonzero, we return it, or if it is zero we go on to subtract the end values and return that.

Subtracting two numeric values is an easy way to generate the negative/zero/positive result for this function. (Note that *any* negative or positive value will do.) And as a nice side effect, it also converts both values to numbers before the subtraction. That's why the code doesn't need `parseInt()` or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

One more boring answer:

```js
var r = /^(\d+)-(\d+)$/;
var ranges = ['3-5', '1-4', '0-9', '10-10'];
ranges.sort(function (a, b) {
  a = a.match(r);
  b = b.match(r);
  a = Math.abs(a[1] - a[2]);
  b = Math.abs(b[1] - b[2]);
  return b - a;
});
document.write(ranges);
```

Comment: Also: ["No need for result of subtraction they're just ranges and not equations!"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/56626641).

Comment: @nicael I bet you are aware that `eval` is highly controversial x-P

Comment: @nicael You seem to like controversy anyway ;-)

Comment: I'm all controversy! You could also make it work with more complicated  expressions ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one more:

```
var ranges = ["3-5", "1-4", "0-9", "10-10"];

ranges.sort(function(a, b) {
 return a.split('-')[0] - b.split('-')[0];
});

console.log(ranges);
```

Output:

```
["0-9", "1-4", "3-5", "10-10"]
```